# Prove there is a solution to the equation $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that its image $f(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded. Prove there is a solution to the equation $f(x)=x$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

---

We want to find a solution to the equation $f(x)-x=0$ which we can do using the intermediate value theorem, if we can show

$\hspace{150pt} f(a)-a<0<f(b)-b$.

---

Since $f(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded, then $\exists M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

$\hspace{160pt} -M\le f(x) \le M$

$\hspace{140pt} -M-x\le f(x) -x\le M-x$

I'm not sure what I can do after this though.

Comment: not x in R. x in f(R).

Comment: Counterexample: $f(x)=\sin x$ is continuous and $f(\mathbb R)=[-1,1]$ is bounded, yet the equation $f(x)=x$ holds only for $x=0$, not "for all $x\in\mathbb R$."

Comment: As bof's comment shows, there's a typo in your first question. It should read "$f(x) = x$ for *some* $x \in \mathbb{R}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $a < -M$; then

$$-M - a \le f(a) - a$$

But by our choice of $a$, it's necessary that $-M - a > 0$, so we have

$$0 < f(a) - a$$

Likewise choose a $b > M$, so that

$$f(b) - b \le M - b < 0$$

Now apply the intermediate value theorem.